# OctoberCMS : Have to go to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, octobercms, ovh

On my OctoberCMS website, I always have to navigate through `index.php`. For example:

- Go to a page : `mywebsite.com/index.php/mypage` instead of `mywebsite.com/mypage`
- Admin : `mywebsite.com/index.php/backend` instead of `mywebsite.com/backend`

All the links are cutently to `mywebsite.com/linktopage` and when I go to `mywebsite.com/index.php`, all the links switched to `mywebsite.com/index.php/linktopage/`. Thats weird.

Here is my `.htaccess`;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Black list protected files
    ##
    RewriteRule ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders and files
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.map
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ico
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.gif
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.less
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.scss
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.swf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xls
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.eot
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff2
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wmv
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp3
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wav
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.avi
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mov
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webm
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ogg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !docs/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/.*
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nanohard](http://octobercms.com/forum/user/nanohard) on OctoberCMS forum, as answered my question.
Here is the answer;

Make sure `mod_rewrite` is `on` using `a2enmod rewrite` and then `service apache2 restart`.

*Source : http://octobercms.com/forum/post/only-index-works?page=1#post-7140*